# sailsjs 1.0 model attribute type date columntype datetime error out in sailsjs

Tags: mysql, datetime, model, sails.js

In sailsjs 1.0@beta I have a model linked to a view in mysql table with mysql-sails@beta adapter.

The model is configured the following way:

```
attributes: {
    id: {type:'number',  required: true},
    'release_date': { type: 'string', columnType: 'datetime' }
  }
```

Although when ever i query the model, sails display a wall of errors per date column:

````
Warning: After transforming columnNames back to attribute names, a record
in the result has a value with an unexpected data type for property `release_date`.
The corresponding attribute declares `type: 'string'` but instead
of that, the actual value is:
```
2016-04-07T05:00:00.000Z
```
````

I have tried to set the type to "datetime" although its no longer supported.

```
The type "datetime" is no longer supported.  To use this type in your model, change
`type` to one of the supported types and set the `columnType` property to a column 
type supported by the model's adapter, e.g. { type: 'string', columnType: 'datetime' }
```

I was not able to find any documentation on what is the proper way to tell sailsjs model that its a date so that sailsjs 1.0b doesn't error out, and is there a way to tell sails its a read only model view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After more digging, found a ticket about this on https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1497

The fix for the datetime issue to use ref instead of string:

```
attributes: {
    id: {type:'number',  required: true},
    'release_date': { type: 'ref', columnType: 'datetime' }
  }
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but with a MongoDB database. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Would you happen to know how I can fix this?

Comment: In that case does this mean that ref is like a javascript object? Basically use ref if nothing else fits?

Comment: @Nag Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

a workaround could be the approach currently found in the SailsJS default web app in the User model:

```
lastSeenAt: {
      type: 'number',
      description: 'A JS timestamp (epoch ms) representing the moment at which this user most recently interacted with the backend while logged in (or 0 if they have not interacted with the backend at all yet).',
      example: 1502844074211
    },
```

then in the UI, you can easily transform this into a human-readable format  by doing, for example, the following:

```
new Date(user.lastSeenAt)
```

Comment: Yes, Also the Sails v1 app has a JSTimestamp component so you can easily convert it for the frontend.